# Ocelot handle HTTP request API with body

Tags: ocelot

I have a HTTP POST API in ASP.NET core as below.

```
 [Route("{code}/bank")]
  public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] string code, [FromBody] BankFilter bank)

    {
            return Ok();
    }
```

How do configure the downstream and upstream in ocelot for the BankFilter model class?

"DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{code}/bank" -- how to accept the bank filter model class?

"UpstreamPathTemplate": "/{code}/bank" -- how to accept the bank filter model class?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure anything. Ocelot would pass the request body to the downstream service.